# iOS serialization/deserialization not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, serialization, deserialization

So I have an object in which I've implemented NS Coding. I've been wracking my brain with this all day. From what I understand, because I've implemented NSCoding, the indexes of the array should be encoded and decoded when the archive/unarchive methods are called on the array itself. So either my understanding of how it works is off, or my implementation has some errors in it.

The file gets written, and the array is deserialized and shows it has an object in it. But the class in the array has no data in it.

The implementation looks like this:

```
#pragma mark NSCoding

#define kTitle              @"Title"
#define kDescription        @"Description"
#define kIsCompleted        @"IsCompleted"
#define kDate               @"Date"
#define kImage              @"Image"

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    [super init];
    title = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:kTitle];
    description = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:kDescription];
    isCompleted = [decoder decodeBoolForKey:kIsCompleted];
    date = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:kDate];
    image = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:kImage];

    return self;
}

-(void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *) encoder
{
    [encoder encodeObject:title forKey:kTitle];
    [encoder encodeObject:description forKey:kDescription];
    [encoder encodeBool:isCompleted forKey:kIsCompleted];
    [encoder encodeObject:date forKey:kDate];
    [encoder encodeObject:image forKey:kImage];
}

@end
```

The encoding looks like this, there' have been some troubleshooting changes:

```
-(void) writeFile
{
    NSData *encodedObject;
    encodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: bucketItems];
    //NSFileHandle *file;
   // file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:filePath];

    //if(true)//file == nil)
    //{
        //NSLog(@"Failed to open a file handle for writing. Attempting to create a file.");
        //[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
        //file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:filePath];
        //if(file == nil)
        //{
         //   NSLog(@"Unable to create new file.");
       // }
    //}

    [encodedObject writeToFile:self.filePath atomically:YES];
    //[file writeData: encodedObject];
    //[file closeFile];
}
```

and then the decoding happens here, the program starts, checks if there's saved data, and loads it

```
NSFileHandle *file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:filePath];
        NSData *fileData;
        fileData = [file readDataToEndOfFile];
        bucketItems = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:fileData];
        NSLog(@"Data file found: loading");
        [file closeFile];
```

Comment: Is initWithCoder getting called??

Comment: yeah it is.. i didn't check that, and it looks like the fields are being decoded.. now why is the array not seeing the properly initialized object

Comment: So bucketItems does end up being the same array, with each item having the correct properties?? Sounds like you are done?? (Use a logger breakpoint to dump it to the console right after it's unarchived..)

Comment: either I'm doing something wrong here:
bucketItems = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:fileData]; 

or in the decoder on the BucketItemClass..

Comment: no.. when bucketItems comes back.. its an array with one "Unknown Class" object in it.. something is off here

Comment: and when i try to access one of the fields, i get a bad access... its like memory isn't be allocated or something

Comment: Are you using ARC? I couldn't get this to compile with ARC but wanted to check.

Comment: i also just tried doing self = [super init] and retaining all the items after decoding.. no dice

Comment: I was reproducing some strange behaviors but self = [super init] and retains during decoding seemed to clear it all up. But I'm using NSKeyedArchiver (un)archive to/from file methods... wonder if your file handling code is at fault.

Comment: ohhhh.. i was autoreleasing after calling retain.. i guess i should call release at dealloc?

Comment: Yeah, if you NARC (new, alloc, retain, copy) any instance variable you'll not want to autorelease it because it will be deallocated very quickly. Hang on to them until `dealloc` or in your setter methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `initWithCoder:` method, I see two things missing - assigning the result of `[super init]` to `self`, and retaining or copying any objects assigned directly to instance variables. You might be able to get away without assigning [super init] to self, but not retaining instance variables will be disastrous.

In a manual reference counting environment, objects don't take ownership of values assigned to instance variables unless a method that transfers ownership is called. Those methods are `new`, `alloc`, `retain`, and `copy`/`mutableCopy` (also Core Foundation create and copy functions). Use the acronym NARC as a mnemonic device for those. Since neither the object that created the objects that were assigned to the ivars (`NSKeyedUnarchiver`) owns them, nor the object itself, they are deallocated. To avoid that, retain or copy the objects you assign to ivars. Copying should be done to prevent unwanted mutation if you suspect the object being assigned might be mutable and is likely to be mutated by another object. Otherwise, retain the values. Finally, ensure that you relinquish ownership of those objects by calling `release` in `dealloc`, or prior to making any further assignments to them (which should be done by synthesized or manually implemented setter methods).

One last thing - you can use `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` methods `archiveRootObject:toFile:` and `unarchiveObjectWithFile:` instead of dealing with file handlers and `NSFileManager`. This will work well for straightforward cases although it has poor error reporting.